# put a vector as a subvector into another vector R

Tags: r, vector

I have a two vectors `(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)` and `(543,544,545)`
I  want to the put second one into the first one starting from the third position, so the result `(1,2,543,544,545,6,7,8)`

```
x <- c(1:8)
r <- c(543:545)

# I tried 
replace(x,3,r)

# or like
replace(3:length(r),1,r)
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: If you read the help at `?replace`, you'll see that `replace(x, 2+1:length(r), r)` does work.

Answer (score 10):

The easiest way is to do it trivially with `c()`:

```
x <- 1:8
r <- c(543,544,545)
c(x[1:2], r ,x[3:length(x)])
```

Another option is `append()`:

```
append(x, values=r, after=2)
```

which does exactly what I did with `c()` before.

If you want to **replace the values** rather than append new ones, you should go with Frank's solution

```
replace(x, list=2+1:length(r), r)
```

or manually

```
x[2+1:length(r)] <- r
```

which modifies `x` instead of creating a new vector.

Comment: Martin, neither of those options give the desire output yet, the idea is to replace (3,4,5) by (543,544,545), not to insert the second vector.

Comment: Agreed, but in his defence he put the desired output in the second line

Comment: The analogue that leaves `x` the same is `\`[<-\`(x, 2+1:length(r), r)`, but that's fugly.

Comment: Worth mentioning anyways :)

Comment: The append solution is new to me. +1

Answer (score 4):

Here is another way. You get the length of a vector you want use, which is `y` in my approach. Then, you indicate specific positions in a vector (i.e., `x`) in order to replace a part of the vector. In this case, you want to tell how many positions you want from the 3rd position in `x` (i.e., `x[c(3:(3+z))]`). You assign `y` in the specified position in `x`.

```
x <- 1:8
y <- 543:545

z <- length(y)-1

x[c(3:(3+z))] <- y

#x
#[1]   1   2 543 544 545   6   7   8
```

Comment: Fwiw, the OP gave a name of `r` to the second vec, not `y`.

Comment: This seems the simplest approach. Essentially it's just `x[3:5] <- r`

Comment: @Frank Thank you for the note. :)